# How to initialize Angular image cropper with image from url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using this [angular image cropper](https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper) lib with Angular 1.6.

The example shows how to crop a file after selecting it from local machine by `input type='file'`.

I want to crop a file that is already uploaded to server. My question is how to initialize the cropper with image having it's url?

Comment: What did you try? any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide base64 String to `cropper.sourceImage` as:

```
function toDataURL(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}

toDataURL('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d50c83cc0c6523b4d3f6085295c953e0',
                    function(dataUrl) {
  $timeout(function() {
        $scope.cropper.sourceImage = dataUrl;
        console.log(dataUrl);
    }, 0);
```

---

We wrap `$scope.cropper.sourceImage = dataUrl;` with `$timeout` to *fire* digest cycle

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/lonuginaqu/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thx!

Comment: Tip for the future: check sources: https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper/blob/master/src/angular-img-cropper.js#L1340